# Convert NSArray to NSMutableArray Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to convert a the `self.assets` `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray` and add it to `picker.selectedAssets` which is a `NSMutableArray`. How will this code look like in swift?

Objective-C Code

```
picker.selectedAssets = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.assets];
```

Comment: Without bothering to look at the docs, I imagine `NSMutableArray(self.assets)` and/or `NSMutableArray.arrayWithArray(self.assets)` would do it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

With Swift 5, `NSMutableArray` has an initializer `init(array:)` that it inherits from `NSArray`. `init(array:)` has the following declaration:

```
convenience init(array anArray: NSArray)
```

> Initializes a newly allocated array by placing in it the objects contained in a given array.

---

The following Playground sample code shows hot to create an instance of `NSMutableArray` from an instance of `NSArray`:

```
import Foundation

let nsArray = [12, 14, 16] as NSArray
let nsMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: nsArray)
nsMutableArray.add(20)
print(nsMutableArray)

/*
prints:
(
    12,
    14,
    16,
    20
)
*/
```

Comment: imagePicker.selectedAssets = NSMutableArray(array: self.assets!) Returns: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: By reading your comment, I guess that `self.assets` is in fact of type `NSArray?`. If so, you should perform an optional binding before assigning it to your NSMutableArray.

Comment: optional binding could i explain?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) then try the following code: `if assets = self.assets {picker.selectedAssets = NSMutableArray(array: assets)}`.

Comment: This line is such a beauty , "let nsMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: nsArray)" , simple but effective ; thank you sir for this answer

Answer (score 3):

You can do the same thing in swift, just modify the syntax a bit:

```
var arr = NSArray()
var mutableArr = NSMutableArray(array: arr)
```

Comment: Should it be `let arr`?

Comment: it could also be let. Since both arrays are only initialized in the snippet, they could both use let. It depends on how you use them after