# IOS - Convert from NSSet to NSMutableSet

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsset

Given an NSSet what is the best way to get an NSMutableSet with those same objects?

To be clear if you have an instance of NSSet what would be the most performant and simple way to get an NSMutable set with those same objects?

Comment: You could get the mutable copy from NSSet object and type cast it into NSMutableSet

let mutableObject = set.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableSet

Comment: @dfd I mean they are asking about how to convert from `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray` and everyone upvotes it as a good question. E.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900567/convert-nsarray-to-nsmutablearray-swift. And this guy asks something like this `Convert from NSSet to NSMutableSet`. It's totally ok. My answer isn't a code-only answer. You can check again

Comment: @AndrewPaulSimmons This is a common pattern in Objective-C; see my explanation at http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch10.html#_immutable_and_mutable

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this.  I felt like it was too hard to find the best way.  I think this question is helpful and the answer from @trungduc below is good.   (However, if down votes go below 10, I'll delete this question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve it.

- Use [mutableCopy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418978-mutablecopy)

  *Objective-C*

  ```
  NSMutableSet* mutableSet2 = [YOUR_SET mutableCopy];
  ```

  *Swift*

  ```
  let mutableSet = YOUR_SET.mutableCopy()
  ```
- Use [setWithSet:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsset/1574817-setwithset)

  *Objective-C*

  ```
  NSMutableSet* mutableSet = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:YOUR_SET];
  ```

  *Swift*

  ```
  let mutableSet = NSMutableSet.init(set: YOUR_SET)
  ```